# How to change entry file (landing page) in intellij

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

I have created a "static web project" in **intelliJ** configured to work with **AngularJS**.
If it has **index.html** in project directory it's working fine(landing page).
And if I remove it from directory structure, **it gives 404 error**.
Okay let **index.html**  be there but I want some other page "say **home.html** to be landing page."
Guess I have to do something in **workspace.xml** file. But exactly what I can't figure out.
I tried by changing <"entry"> tag inside <"file"> tag in workspace.xml to home.html, but didn't work out.